# firebase set data with user token

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi there question about how to receive the user token when inserting data in firebase

currently I insert data with something like this:

```
const itemRef = this.db.object('/test/'+  this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).set({ test: test});
```

Where I get the user UID and put it inside the database. This works fine however but when I do this again the data will be overwritten. So I want something like this

```
Hardware/uid/random_token/(data)
```

however I cannot seem to find on how to get the user token

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What on earth is Hardware/uid/random_token/(data)

Comment: @Bcoded read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Authentication, you can get the currentUser from that.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```